# Update table's column with values from another table's column

Tags: mysql

I have a table with random names (along with an id as primary key):

```
CREATE TABLE `people` (
  `id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

I have inserted in it 100 random names along with their ids. I also have another table with other names:

```
CREATE TABLE `names` (
  `id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

This table also has 100 (different) random names along with their ids. I want to update the column `name` of table `people` with the names from the column `name` of table `names`.

I obviously have to use `UPDATE` and `SET` but in most ways I saw that people are also using `INNER JOIN`. Personally, I am wondering if there is simpler way to do this (without using `INNER JOIN`) and I am missing it?

Comment: the simple way is the one based on inner  join  ..and also the  more clear., compact and expressive..

Comment: Ok, thanks for your comment. You can write your answer below and I can tick it if you want.

Comment: I have posted  a update sample based  on inner join  for mysql and brierf explantion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the update with inner join as eg:

```
update people
inner join names on people.id = names.id 
set people.name = names.name
```

Is the simplest and also the more clear, compact and expressive.

others methods need normally subselect  or implicit join based on where condition. In one case there query is more verbouse and in the second the query is more confused and often  less performant.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, if this is the simplest way to do a simple update to one table from another one then perhaps I may be justified to claim that SQL sucks, at least a bit...haha...

Comment: I can understand that this form of queries may be useful to maintain consistency and structure when dealing with very large databases but for something that simple I would not expect to use `INNER JOIN` etc...